# How to Get latitude and longitude from Google Maps React onClick

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, maps, coordinates, google-map-react

i want to get the coordinates of google map react onclick.
this is my code :

```
return (
    <GoogleMapReact
      google={this.props.google}
      styles={customizeMap}
      style= {ukuran}
      zoom={15}
      onClick={(e) => {
        console.log("latitude = ", e.latLng.lat());
        console.log("longtitude = ", e.latLng.lng());
      }}
      initialCenter={!!this.props.places && this.props.places ? (
        { lat: this.props.places.lat, lng: this.props.places.lng}
      ):({ lat: -7.747872, lng: 110.4218147  })}>
      <Marker 
        position={!!this.props.places && this.props.places ? (
          { lat: this.props.places.lat, lng: this.props.places.lng}
        ):({ lat: -7.747872, lng: 110.4218147  })}
        icon={{
          url: Icon,
          scaledSize:  new this.props.google.maps.Size(70, 55)
        }}
      />
    </GoogleMapReact>
);
```

and this is the message returned on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')
    at Object.onClick (halteMap.js:58:1)
    at index.js:311:1
```

Comment: a good tip to debug this issues of undefined, i will do the following,
start your console.log at the parent element of the object

console.log("latitude", e) then see the property you want and from the keep going further

Answer (score 0):

this is late answer but in my case this worked:

```
onClick={(e) => {
    console.log("latitude = ", e.lat)
    console.log("longtitude = ", e.lng);
}}
```